# Draggable background/area in vis.js timeline for selecting a time period

Tags: javascript, vis.js

We would like to have an editable time range on the `vis.js` timeline in the same way as an event can be edited. So 1) the user could drag backwards or forwards in time if they grab by the middle, and also 2) edit the length by grabbing and dragging either and of the area.
The editing and their callbacks work very well on the items themselves, but not on the backgrounds. The goal is to let the user to select an interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to drag backgrounds or change their size like the items. But what you can do is to add new items with a field to differentiate them from others items and with custom css, you can modify them to look like backgrounds and the drag and resize will works on these "new" backgrounds.

Comment: Yes, that was our plan B too, but wanted to go for a more supported solution as opposed to this workaround. Will report here, if/when we get somewhere with this.